# Maximal value of domain for a function by looking at inverse function.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse, integral-domain

The function g:[–a,a]→ R, g(x)=sin(2(x-π/6))has an inverse function.The maximum possible value of a is:

From what I understand the domain of g(x) is the range of g'(x). So I would try to find the inverse equation, work out the range, and then use this information to find the value of a, in the domain.

[image]

but i'm stuck at finding the range.

note: if i enter π/2 the calc says undefined so i'm assuming the value of a is π/2.

the answer is out of: π/12, 1, π/6, π/4, π/2

Comment: You may find this [guide to writing math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) useful in formatting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sin(2(x-\pi/6))=\sin(2x - \pi/3)$$

$\sin$ has an inverse in the interval $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.
So
$$
-\pi/2 \le 2x-\pi/3 \le \pi/2 \\
-\pi/2+\pi/3\le 2x \le \pi/2 + \pi/3 \\
-\pi/12 \le x \le 5\pi/12
$$
So $[-a, a]$ should fit into $[-\pi/12, 5\pi/12]$
So $$a = \pi/12$$

The following was my original answer and is wrong! Please disregard. I was not thinking right!

---

Note that $\sin x$ has an inverse in an interval of length $\pi$. So $\sin 2x$ must have an inverse over an interval of length $\pi/2$. So $a=\pi/4$.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what an interval length is.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Uh... where? is it?

Comment: sorry, I am a slow typist :)

Comment: i dont understand how you get pi/6 on both sides? Can you explain please?

haha, it's okay, I'm slower :(

Comment: I got pi/6 because I wanted to write pi/3 but wrote pi/6. It is fixed.

Comment: oh great! so with these inverse intervals? Is there a set one for cos/sin and tan? Do you know a link that talks more about inverse for trig? Cause I had no idea sin was inverse in-between those two values. I'd like to see it as a drawing, so I know what's going on, but I dont know where to even begin looking.

Comment: You know how you would normally go about finding inverse domains and range? Like I had done in my working out? Well this clearly doesn't apply to this question. So I'm assuming for all similar trig/inverse questions i would go about it like you did. Is this correct to believe?

Comment: Yeah for trig functions, you have to look at the graph and decide. $\sin$ is 1-1 between $-pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. (also between $\pi/2$ and $\3 pi/2$). Cosine is 1-1 from zero to $\pi$ (and also $\pi$ to $2 \pi$). You just have to pick the right interval depending on the problem.

Comment: so instead of writing -pi/2 can i write 3pi/2?

For cosine- does it matter if you write zero instead of 2pi when working it out... etc?

Comment: yes, you just have to pick the interval so it contains the value you want. In this case you want $2x-pi/3$ should contain zero since you are looking for $[-a,a]$

Comment: okay yes, i got it - so look at the domain, and make a judgement?